# Криво работает screenOrientation

Tags: android

В сервисе есть следующий код:

```
g_shadow_view = new View(this);
g_winM = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
g_shadow_params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(0,0,
LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|
LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND|
LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
g_shadow_params.screenOrientation=-1;
g_winM.addView(g_shadow_view, g_shadow_params);
```

Переменные g_shadow_view, g_winM, g_shadow_params объявлены глобально внутри класса.

Код, отвечающий за смену ореинтации

```
`g_shadow_params.screenOrientation= XXX;
g_winM.updateViewLayout(g_shadow_view, g_shadow_params);`
```

где всместо ХХХ подставляю одно из следующих значений:

```
`
    SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED -1
    SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR 10
    SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE 0
    SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT 1
    SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE 8
    SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT 9
    SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE 6
    SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT 7
`
```

На виртуальной машине работает всё, а на реальных устройствах не работают режимы
SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT и SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT. Всё остальное работает исправно. В чём может быть загвоздка?

Comment: Значит само устройство не поддерживает REVERSE_PORTRAIT. Попробуйте его повертеть в других приложениях.

Comment: поддержка REVERSE_PORTRAIT (поворот на 180 градусов) должна присутствовать в прошивке (в большинстве - запрещено), проверить можно на CyanogenMod/LineageOS после разрешения этого в настройках

Comment: SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR 10 - в этом режиме при переворачивании устройтсва экран тоже переворачивается.